# Shell or AWK assistance, how can I substitute a specific text from one file to another file?

Tags: shell, awk

File 1 - list of CSV files

```
Run_100000_data.csv
Run_101001_data.csv
Run_102002_data.csv
...
...
```

(Please note that the list above could grow and files are always in this structure `Run_6digit#_data.csv`.)

File 2

```
LINEMAP [1]
NAME = '&M#&'
LINEMAP [2]
NAME = '&M#&'
LINEMAP [3]
NAME = '&M#&'
```

I would like to write a shell script that substitutes the 1st line of File 1 with the first instance of `&M#&` found in File 2. This would repeat for the second and third line or as many lines as are in the file.

Output:

```
LINEMAP [1]
NAME = 'Run_100000'
LINEMAP [2]
NAME = 'Run_101001'
LINEMAP [3]
NAME = 'Run_102002'
```

Please note I'm not using the full name from File 1, ('_data.csv' is not used). If the run number can be substituted then that would be acceptable too. I would like to leave this open ended to allow for any creative ideas. Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: In file 2, are the lines with the string to be replaced always on every second line, or might they be anywhere?

Comment: sorry for the delayed response... string to be replaced could be anywhere. I tried your bash script and that worked like a charm! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a Bash script that does it:

```
#!/bin/bash

macro='&M#&'

while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line == *${macro}* ]]; then
        # Read replacement from fd 3 / file1
        read -r -u 3 rpl
        # Compose output line with parameter substitutions
        printf '%s%s%s\n' "${line%"$macro"*}" "${rpl%_data.csv}" "${line#*"$macro"}"
    else
        printf '%s\n' "$line"
    fi
# Read from file2, redirect fd 3 to read from file1, redirect output to outfile
done < file2 3< file1 > outfile
```

This redirects `file1` to file descriptor 3 so we can read from there when we want during the loop. The rest is pattern matching and parameter expansions.

---

If `file2` has the lines with the string to be replaced on every second line, we can use `paste` and sed as follows:

```
paste -d ' ' file2 <(paste -d '\n' /dev/null file1) |
    sed 's/&M#&\(.*\) \([^[:blank:]]*\)_data\.csv$/\2\1/'
```

Explanation:

- `paste -d '\n' /dev/null file1` interleaves `file1` with empty lines, resulting in

  ```
  ​
  Run_100000_data.csv

  Run_101001_data.csv

  Run_102002_data.csv
  ```
- `paste -d ' ' file2 <(paste -d '\n' /dev/null file1)` pastes that together with `file2`, space separated:

  ```
  LINEMAP [1]
  NAME = '&M#&' Run_100000_data.csv
  LINEMAP [2]
  NAME = '&M#&' Run_101001_data.csv
  LINEMAP [3]
  NAME = '&M#&' Run_102002_data.csv
  ```
- `sed 's/&M#&\(.*\) \([^[:blank:]]*\)_data\.csv$/\2\1/'` checks for the string to be replaced, captures everything up to the last blank on the line and the part of the replacement we want and rearranges it, resulting in

  ```
  LINEMAP [1]
  NAME = 'Run_100000'
  LINEMAP [2]
  NAME = 'Run_101001'
  LINEMAP [3]
  NAME = 'Run_102002'
  ```

Comment: The bash script worked perfectly! Thank you so much for taking time to help me out on this! I should have mentioned that File 2 contains other lines so replacing the string on every second line would not work in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
BEGIN { str = "&M#&" }
NR==FNR { sub(/_[^_]+$/,""); a[NR] = $0; next }
s = index($0,str) { $0 = substr($0,1,s-1) a[++c] substr($0,s+length(str)) }
{ print }
' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in my tests with gnu awk:

```
echo "$a"
Run_100000_data.csv
Run_101001_data.csv
Run_102002_data.csv

echo "$b"
LINEMAP [1]
NAME = '&M#&'
LINEMAP [2]
NAME = '&M#&'
LINEMAP [3]
NAME = '&M#&'

awk -F"_" 'NR==FNR{f[FNR]=$1FS$2;next}FNR%2!=0{print $1;print "NAME = \x27"f[++c]"\x27"}' <(echo "$a") <(echo "$b")
LINEMAP [1]
NAME = 'Run_100000'
LINEMAP [2]
NAME = 'Run_101001'
LINEMAP [3]
NAME = 'Run_102002'
```

In above test i use two variables. In your case you can use

```
awk -F"_" 'NR==FNR{f[FNR]=$1FS$2;next}FNR%2!=0{print $1;print "NAME = \x27"f[++c]"\x27"}' file1 file2
```

Comment: forgive me, I'm not familiar with $ echo "$a". I use bash, when I echo the csvList.txt it doesn't show me what the content is.... it simply echo's the name back.

Comment: @user7649922 OK, i will clarify it in my answer

Comment: @user7649922 OK-Clarified.

Comment: Use octal not hex for `'` (i.e. `\047`, not `\x27`), see http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote.

Comment: Slight problem, File 2 contains other lines (that I didn't mention) and it seems to corrupt things or remove certain pieces of data when I run your code. I should have mention this earlier. Can your script be adapted to deal with this situation?